# double selection probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, conditional-probability

> [image]

What I think we need to use $n+r-1\choose{r-1}$ for the pair $x+y=100$
I tried something like this there are total 24 pairs whose sum is 100 and 49 total odd so first selection will be $49\choose24$

After that i am stumped what to do ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Can you construct an example in which no two element sum is equal to $100$?

Can you construct a set with less than 26 elements with no two elements sum is equal to $100$?

Feel free to ask for more clarification :)

Comment: I guess no as there are 24 pairs , which means 48 used so remaining only is 1 ,.. so we need 1 more to have a pair... so which is not possible ! so you mean probability is 1 always ? @TheHolyJoker

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Thanks but I hope you are sure .. because i am not sure./

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure? you gave a sketch of a proof. I suggest you write an answer that is more formal, using [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Thanks... let me see it

Comment: If you are having trouble with it, please let me know

Comment: i dont understand pigeonhole thing... but if you say my way of thinking is correct then i can write a theory and some sample space thing to explain there cant be any pair whose sum not 100...

Comment: The Pigeonhole Principle is basically saying if you divide $n$ apples between $n-1$ people, at least one person would get at least $2$ apples.

Comment: hahaha awesome never thought this way thanks !!!